# Google Maps API using SSMS Database

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an application that I would like to show upcoming Expos from around the United States. I was initially pointed in the direction of a Places API, then I was pointed towards the Geocoding API. So far nothing has worked. My code is going to seem choppy on behalf of so many different sources and trying to mesh things together to get it to work.

I'm using a SQL Server database and I have a table with ExpoLocations, I have fields for address, city, state, and Zipcode. I'm trying to create a javascript array using c# to plug into my API. I am not getting any Console Errors. In my Inspector, when I look at sources, it is returning the items I need in the Array. The map I not displaying at all on my page.

All code is on my View

div>
id=mapAPI

```
    // #region MAP API       
    var expos = [];
    @foreach (var item in Model.ToList())
    {
        @:var request = { types: 'street_address', formatted_address: '@item.Address' + '@item.City' + ',' + '@item.State', address_components:{types: 'street_address'}, partial_match: true}
            @:expos.push(request);
            }



    var geocoder;
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: latlng
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapAPI'), mapOptions);
    }

    function codeAddress() {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(request, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
    // #endregion
```

I am using this API in my scripts

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that initialize() is actually being called once your document renders.
2. Ensure that your map div has a minimum height.

You should then at least be able to see a map on your page.

Then, the problem is that the response variable for your callback from `geocoder.geocode` is named `request`, but you are using `results[0].geometry.location` to actually set the map location.

Change the name in your callback to `results` and you should see the marker for your geocoded location when `codeAddress` is called.

You'll have some additional work to do if you want to geocode each of the addresses in your results array, but hopefully this should at least get a map rendered for you.

You should be able to run the snippet below with your API key.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURKEYHERE"></script>
<script>
  var geocoder;
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    console.log("initialize called");
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: latlng
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapAPI'), mapOptions);
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    console.log("codeAddress called!");
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!");
    initialize();
  });
</script>
<div id="mapAPI" style="min-width:100px;min-height:100px"></div>
<input id="address" />
<button onClick="codeAddress()">Geocode Me!</button>
```